# psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected when running COPY command

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a huge file that i am trying to write to my postgres table. This file has around ~500k rows.

I am using this method to input the files to the

```
class BKngLoader():

   .
   .
   .

    # method to save to db 
    def _save_to_db(self):  # pragma: no cover
        """upload the data to the database"""
        self.logger.info("Saving to database")
        try:
            # get DB connection strings & initialize DB connection.
            connection_string = get_db_connection_string()
            init_app(connection_string)
            from rail_sora_data.database.postgresql import SESSION
            connection = SESSION.bind.raw_connection()
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            command = "COPY rail.booking_curve FROM stdin "
            command += "WITH NULL AS '' DELIMITER '|' HEADER CSV"

            with open('booking_curve.csv', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
                cursor.copy_expert(command, data_file)
            connection.commit()
            SESSION.commit()
        except SQLAlchemyError as exc:
            print(exc)




I am not sure what is causing this error.

FYI It is not consistent, i.e sometimes it is able to complete the copy to DB without failing.
```